# Having issues running multiple geocoder callbacks

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, google-geocoder

I am currently trying to wrap my head around the asynchronous nature of Node. I am currently experimenting with Geocoder however I cant seem to figure out the root of the problem. My current express route handler is as shown

```
app.get('/:location/:next_location', (req, res) => {
    geocoder.geocode(req.params.location, function ( err, data ) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        var location1, location2
        location1 = data

        console.log(location1.results[0].geometry)
        geocoder.geocode(req.params.next_location, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
            location2 = data

            console.log(location2.results[0].geometry)
        });
        res.send('Ok')
    });
});
```

When I hit this route I am getting

```
/Users/dannyxxx/Desktop/react/node-yelp/server.js:47
            console.log(location2.results[0].geometry)
                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined
```

thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

```
function geocodePromise(data){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        geocoder.geocode(data, function (err, data) {
        if (data) { resolve(data) }
        })
    })
}

var points = {}
    geocodePromise(req.params.location)
    .then((data)=> {
        points.location1 = data.results[0].geometry.location
        return geocodePromise(req.params.next_location)
    })
    .then(data => {
        points.location2 = data.results[0].geometry.location
    })
```

Comment: What do you see if you log location2? `console.log(localtion2.results)`. If the `localtion2.results` is empty or not an array, you would be getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined`

Comment: Probably you are facing ZERO_RESULTS for second location. Can you check the exact response status before retrieving the geometry?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes What is exact value for the location that doesn't have geometry?

Comment: I actually went ahead and wrapped the function inside a promise as shown in the edit to force the request to behave in a synchronous manner, thank you guys, you've been a big help